# How to get the Debian codename without lsb_release

Tags: debian, version, lsb-release

I am trying to create a script that requires me to print the Debian codename so that I may echo it into the `sources.list` file.

I am trying to make this script work across any version of Debian, so I had hoped to set a bash variable of the release codename.
This would be simple to do with `lsb_release -c`.
However, our deployment images do not contain `lsb_release` by default - and with this script being required to fix the `sources.list`, installing `lsb-release` with `apt-get` would not be an option.

I have found numerous ways to get the release number and other info about the system, but cannot find a reliable place to get the codename.

(I am testing this with Debian Squeeze.)

Comment: If you googled this while considering dropping `lsb_release`, check out [it's source code](https://sources.debian.org/src/lsb-release/1.4-8/lsb_release/) and see if you're willing to reinvent all that

Answer (score 27):

You can use `/etc/os-release`:

```
(
  . /etc/os-release
  printf '%s\n' "$VERSION"
)
7 (wheezy)
```

Answer (score 20):

For Debian distributions that don't ship with `/etc/os-release` (like Squeeze), you can use the following "hack". It exploits that the `tzdata` package provides a capability<sup>(1)</sup> that includes that name:

```
$ dpkg --status tzdata
Package: tzdata
...
Provides: tzdata-squeeze
```

So, you can post-process this to extract that part of the capability name:

```
dpkg --status tzdata|grep Provides|cut -f2 -d'-'
```

or, with less piping

```
dpkg --status tzdata|awk -F'[:-]' '$1=="Provides"{print $NF}'
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> that's RedHat terminology, though

Comment: Yooo, bro. This is sick!
Exactly what I needed. Anything else in Linux Mint LMDE (Debian Edition) doesn't display the Debian version that the Mint was built on. But your solution does. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You can get the codename of your Debian distribution from `/etc/os-release`. Instead of attempting to parse this file, you can source it into a fresh environment, so as not to impact your current environment, and execute an `echo` command in that new environment.

```
env -i bash -c '. /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_CODENAME'
```

To break it down:

- `env` : Run a command in a new environment.
- `-i` : Do not inherit the environment variables from the existing environment.
- `bash` : Run bash so that we have a shell to source the os-release file into, and to run the echo command.
- `-c` : Tell `bash` we want to execute a command rather than start an interactive shell.
- `. /etc/os-release` : Source the contents of `os-release` into our new environment. `os-release` contains a few lines setting environment variables, and this will set those environment variables in our new environment.
- `;` : Separate this command and run the next command.
- `echo $VERSION_CODENAME` : Echo out the code name that was set by the `os-release` file.

Comment: Great answer, I learned you to use such files from it. I used it like this `echo "$(. /etc/os-release && echo $VERSION_CODENAME"` but noticed that there's no `$VERSION_CODENAME` in `stretch`. Very sad news.

Comment: I fixed it like this `echo "$(. /etc/os-release && echo ${VERSION_CODENAME-stretch})"` which seems ok for my task, but it looks bad

Comment: This looks like the most elegant approach (at least thanks to no parsing involved)

Answer (score 6):

You can print code along with version number of debian:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# grep "VERSION=" /etc/os-release |awk -F= {' print $2'}|sed s/\"//g
8 (jessie)
```

OR you can bare your code name from number and pranthese:

```
grep "VERSION=" /etc/os-release |awk -F= {' print $2'}|sed s/\"//g |sed s/[0-9]//g | sed s/\)$//g |sed s/\(//g
jessie
```

Comment: Or, more idiomatically: `awk -F= '/VERSION=/ {gsub(/"/,""); print $2}'
/etc/os-release`

Comment: @jasonwryan Even `awk -F"[=\"]+" '/VERSION=/ {print $2}' /etc/os-release`

Comment: @Costas my output is only codename.

Comment: If you'd like just code-name it is much simple `awk -F"[)(]+" '/VERSION=/ {print $2}' /etc/os-release`

Answer (score 2):

For systemd:

```
hostnamectl | grep "Operating System"
```

output:

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
```

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: This surely does not work on Debian Squeeze as Debian Squeeze did not have a systemd package. And even with Debian 8 Jessie (where systemd became the default init system), hostnamectl is only installed if systemd is installed, so this solution won't work if the system in question uses one of the other 3 or 4 init systems Debian offers.

Answer (score 1):

this one might (or might not) be an alternate approach to what bcoca wrote on Debian squeeze - i tested it Ubuntu 18.04:

```
$ cat /etc/debian_version
buster/sid
```

Answer (score 0):

Another heuristic is to see where the packages for the currently running OS come from.

Simple (and probably error-prone) variant:

```
fgrep -r /debian/ /etc/apt/sources.list \
    | egrep -v '^ *#' \
    | awk '{print $3}' \
    | egrep -v '[-/]'  \
    | uniq
```

A more reliable way is to parse the details out of the output of `apt-cache policy` (without further parameter):

```
apt-cache policy \
    | fgrep o=Debian, \
    | fgrep ,l=Debian, \
    | fgrep ,c=main, \
    | awk -F '[,=]' '{print $6}'
```

`apt-cache policy` lists all APT repositories in use on the local system. We filter out those which originate from Debian, which are labeled just `Debian` (i.e. not those labeled e.g. `Debian debug`), then only look at the main archive (not `contrib` or `non-free`) and then select the according value.

An even more stable approach would be to not rely on the element order and find the `n=` value in the remaining line:

```
apt-cache policy \
    | fgrep o=Debian, \
    | fgrep ,l=Debian, \
    | fgrep ,c=main, \
    | egrep -o 'n=[^, ]*' \
    | awk -F= '{print $2}'
```

Yet another possibility would be to parse the `/var/lib/apt/lists/*Release` files yourself instead of letting `apt-cache` do that:

```
egrep -l '^Origin: Debian$' /var/lib/apt/lists/*Release \
    | xargs egrep -l '^Label: Debian$' \
    | xargs egrep -L 'Codename: .*-' \
    | xargs fgrep Codename \
    | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

My need was to add some URL in sources.list. And to be able to dynamically put version code name, I use this piece of code (rely on the fact that code name is between parenthesis) : Inspired by [@PersianGulf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/21911/persiangulf) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180779/64096).

`grep "VERSION=" /etc/os-release |awk -F= {' print tolower($2)'}|sed s/\.*\(//g | sed s/" ".*\"//g`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon [@Costas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/89144/costas) answer, that command didn't work for 16.04 where it returned the full name "Xerial Xerus" but I only wanted "xerial" as that is how the repo I was trying to pull from separated the different versions. This command adds that only the first word will be returned, and that it will be all lowercase:

```
awk -F"[)(]+" '/VERSION=/ {print $2}' /etc/os-release | awk '{print $1}' | awk '{ print tolower($0) }'
```

This works for "jessie" as well

Answer (score 0):

Only using `grep`:

```
grep -Po 'VERSION="[0-9]+ \(\K[^)]+' /etc/os-release
```

Try it (output as of writing this post):

```
$ docker run --rm debian:stable-slim grep -Po 'VERSION="[0-9]+ \(\K[^)]+' /etc/os-release
stretch
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave this here :)

```bsh
sed -e "0,/_.*_/s/.*_\(.*\)_.*/\1/;t;d" /var/lib/apt/cdroms.list
```

Edit: It's matching the first `_<string>_` inside `/var/lib/apt/cdroms.list`

Comment: This did show `jessie` after upgrading to `stretch`, while `env -i bash -c '. /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_CODENAME'
` returned the correct version: `stretch`

Answer (score 0):

#### How to get the Debian codename without lsb_release

If you want *only* the codename and nothing else :

```
$ (. /etc/os-release; printf '%s\n' "$VERSION_CODENAME";)
bullseye
```

If you want to mimic `lsb_release -c` :

```
$ (. /etc/os-release; printf 'Codename: %s\n' "$VERSION_CODENAME";)
Codename: bullseye
```

If you want to mimic `lsb_release -d` :

```
$ (. /etc/os-release; printf 'Description: %s %s\n' "$NAME" "$VERSION";)
Description: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
```

#### Reference

- [Elegant answer that outputs version number and codename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180778)