# How to programmatically get the Debian codename of 'testing'?

Tags: debian

As per the title, I'd like to resolve the Debian codename (e.g. "stretch", "buster", "bullseye", etc) of the current "testing".

Obviously there are a variety of ways to do this within an installed Debian "testing" system (e.g. `lsb_release -sc`, among others as noted in answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/180776/60506)). But how do I do this from a Debian 'stable' (or even an alternate Linux distro)?

For example, I'm running Debian 'stable' (currently Debian 'buster') - how do I reliably determine what codename 'testing' currently has?

I realise that currently 'testing' = 'bullseye', but when 'bullseye' is released as 'stable', that will change (to 'bookworm' IIRC).

Answer (score 11):

Alternate method: install the package [`distro-info`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/distro-info) (pulling `distro-info-data`), from backports if available there, and run:

```
distro-info --testing
```

For example currenly, on Debian 9 oldstable, with distro-info 0.21~bpo9+1 from stretch-backports:

```
$ distro-info --testing
bullseye
$ distro-info --fullname --testing
Debian 11 "Bullseye"
```

Had the package version for `distro-info-data` be kept to stretch/oldstable 0.14, the result would have been obsolete: `buster`, but that's because it's *oldstable*. Expect it to be up to date on *stable* for the next *testing* codename, and up to date in the previous release's *backports*.

```
$ distro-info --fullname --all|tail
Debian 5.0 "Lenny"
Debian 6.0 "Squeeze"
Debian 7 "Wheezy"
Debian 8 "Jessie"
Debian 9 "Stretch"
Debian 10 "Buster"
Debian 11 "Bullseye"
Debian 12 "Bookworm"
Debian  "Sid"
Debian  "Experimental"
```

Comment: Nice one! I wasn't aware of that package. I note that the `distro-info-data` package contains the info within a csv file, so if the program could read csv data, that could even be read directly from there.

Comment: Yes but why bother when there's an easy command going along with it.

Comment: Because then there's no need to call an external application. I wasn't necessarily recommending it as the "best path", I was just noting it as a possibility.

Answer (score 9):

To answer my own question, it turns out it's actually pretty easy...:

```
curl -sL https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/InRelease | grep "^Codename:" | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Currently that returns:

```
bullseye
```

Comment: Use `-sL` to make `curl` quiet and follow redirects if any

Comment: This seems to require an internet connection, is that not a problem?

Comment: @bobsburner - You are correct, it does require an internet connection. It wasn't an issue for me, but it certainly could be if you didn't have internet. The other answer here doesn't require an internet connection at the time, but does still require package installation (and the info will become outdated). I can't imagine how you might be able to determine this reliably without internet (at some point), but if you know, please share.

Comment: Why the recent downvotes (4 in total in the last month!)? If there is something wrong with this answer please post a comment rather than just downvoting... FWIW, this still works for me...