# Why lsb_release -c command , returns n/a?

Tags: deepin, lsb, lsb-release, deepin-desktop-environment

recently I switched from **zorin os** to **deepin 20** for it's outstanding UI and eases of use for daily operations.

it's almost OK but if I need some newer packages which are not listed in official deepin repositories, I have to use some community installer scripts that rely on this command to obtain the correct linux LSB version :

`lsb_release -c`

the problem is : **the return value is "n/a"** that consequently, breaks down the installation process. how can I fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Debian codename without lsb-release](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180776/how-to-get-debian-codename-without-lsb-release)

Comment: It's Helped Me. But I want to correct the result of lsb_release (to things work well at deepin) - thanks . @StephenKitt

Comment: OK, so please [edit] your question to explain that (your answer gives the impression that the question linked above solved your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out the **partial solution** (because i could not correct the codename section of lsb_release result) that had me get rid of this error :

*just replace the command :*

`lsb_release -c`

with :

`dpkg --status tzdata|grep Provides|cut -f2 -d'-'`

***in every script that uses the first one.***

Thanks to [bcoca](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/180776/how-to-get-debian-codename-without-lsb-release/253476#253476)

Comment: Can lsb_release be aliased to return the value of your suggested command?

Answer (score 0):

Put `LSB_VERSION="something"` in `/etc/lsb-release`.